# How to show/hide the slice of a pieChart when tapped on legend in coreplot

Tags: objective-c, core-plot, pie-chart

I am trying to showing and hiding of the slice of the piechart when tapped on legend item in coreplot. But need some suggestions or inputs how to get with this or start up with this.

Comment: Do you want to remove the selected slice or change the fill to make the background show through?

Comment: @EricSkroch: I want to make the slice fill to the background fill color.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the `-sliceFillForPieChart:recordIndex:` method in the plot datasource. Return a transparent fill (`[CPTFill fillWithColor:[CPTColor clearColor]]`) for the index of the slice you want to hide. Call `-reloadData` on the plot whenever you need to update the fills.

If you pull the latest code to get a change I just made (after release 1.4), you can also return `[NSNull null]` from the datasource to get the same effect with better drawing performance.

Comment: How to handle if I want to remove the slice itself... instead making the slice fillColor to transparent

Comment: Use the `deleteDataInIndexRange:` method to remove one or more slices. Note that this reduces the number of data points in the plot, so the index numbering will be different if you later add more data to the plot.

Comment: tanq for the suggestions.